# Unity Command Line -- executeMethod and logFile not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get started with Unity Command Line arguments and trying to simply make an editor function that writes to a file. If I run the function from within Unity, it works and I can successfully see the contents of the file, but when I'm trying to call it from the command prompt, it doesn't give any error messages in the console (and even if I change the name of the function to something that doesn't exist, it doesn't giev any errors either.. so also it would be cool to get an error stdout if possible). Here's my basic unity class (that works when called from within unity):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.IO;

public class CobysBundleBuilder {
    public static void CobyBuildIt() {
        var path = "Assets/test.txt";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        writer.WriteLine("Hi there!");
        writer.Close();
        Debug.Log("ASDFGG");
        MonoBehaviour.print("wow");
    }
}
```

And this is the command I'm calling from the command line, I don't even see a logFile created:

```
C:\"Program Files"\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Unity.exe -batchmode -quit -projectPath C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\"totally empty"\"New Unity Project" -executeMethod CobysBundleBuilder.CobyBuildIt -logFile C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop
```

So first of all the desired file, which is placed in my assets folder (test.txt), isn't being written to (like it is when called from within Unity), and also the logfile isn't appearing on my desktop.

Am  I missing something basic? I'm just trying to test the Unity command line arguments and get something basic to work.

Thanks, if anyone knows how to fix it.

P.S.:

Also it might be possible that the projectPath parameter might not be working, since when I call the command without -batchmode and -quit it just opens up the unity hub with a list of all my projects, but doesn't open the specific project passed as the paramter.

EDIT: 
I tried putting the script in my Assets/Editor folder and checked the Editor.Log file in AppData and this is what it says (I changed the function BTW):

```
LICENSE SYSTEM [2019219 0:41:36] Next license update check is after 2018-08-28T23:32:35


LICENSE SYSTEM [2019219 0:41:36] 00342-20100-00000-AAOEM != 00342-20108-34498-AAOEM

Built from '2019.1/staging' branch; Version is '2019.1.0b1 (83b3ba1f99df) revision 8631226'; Using compiler version '191627012'
OS: 'Windows 10  (10.0.0) 64bit' Language: 'en' Physical Memory: 11743 MB
BatchMode: 1, IsHumanControllingUs: 0, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 0, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 0
[Package Manager] Server::Start -- Port 54964 was selected

 COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Unity
-batchmode
-quit
-projectPath
C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty
-executeMethod
MyScript.MyMethod
Successfully changed project path to: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty
C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/totally empty
Using Asset Import Pipeline V1.
DisplayProgressbar: Unity Package Manager
Loading GUID <-> Path mappings...0.000110 seconds
Loading Asset Database...0.016790 seconds
AssetDatabase consistency checks...0.049615 seconds
[Package Manager] Done resolving packages in 0.74s seconds
[Package Manager] Registering 38 packages:
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.ads@2.0.8
    (location: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ads@2.0.8)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.analytics@3.2.2
    (location: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.analytics@3.2.2)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.15
    (location: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.15)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.package-manager-ui@2.1.1
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.package-manager-ui)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.purchasing@2.0.1
    (location: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.purchasing@2.0.1)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3.0
    (location: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3.0)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.timeline@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.timeline)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@1.0.0)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.ai@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.ai)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.animation@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.animation)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.assetbundle@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.assetbundle)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.audio@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.audio)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.cloth@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.cloth)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.director@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.director)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.imageconversion@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.imageconversion)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.imgui@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.imgui)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.jsonserialize@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.jsonserialize)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.particlesystem@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.particlesystem)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.physics@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.physics)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.physics2d@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.physics2d)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.screencapture@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.screencapture)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.terrain@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.terrain)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.terrainphysics@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.terrainphysics)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.tilemap@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.tilemap)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.ui@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.ui)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.uielements@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.uielements)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.umbra@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.umbra)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.unityanalytics@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.unityanalytics)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.vehicles@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.vehicles)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.video@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.video)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.vr@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.vr)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.wind@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.wind)
[Package Manager]  * Package :  com.unity.modules.xr@1.0.0
    (location: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.modules.xr)
[Package Manager] Done registering packages in 0.01s seconds
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 18.94 ms, found 2 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Initialize engine version: 2019.1.0b1 (83b3ba1f99df)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: AMD Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics (ID=0x9874)
    Vendor:   
    VRAM:     3433 MB
    Driver:   22.19.180.513
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.14 seconds
[EnlightenBakeManager] m_Clear = false;
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'AR/TangoARRender' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'AR/TangoARRender' - Setting to default shader.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VideoDecodeOSX' - Pass 'Flip_RGBARect_To_RGBA' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VideoDecodeOSX' - Setting to default shader.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VideoDecodeAndroid' - Pass 'RGBAExternal_To_RGBA' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VideoDecodeAndroid' - Setting to default shader.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VideoDecodeML' - Pass 'RGBAExternal_To_RGBA' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VideoDecodeML' - Setting to default shader.
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.0b1/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.0b1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/unityjit'
Mono config path = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.0b1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:56428
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.97 ms, found 3 plugins.
Initializing Extension Manager v2019.1.0 for Unity v2019.1.0b1
Registering precompiled unity dll's ...
Register platform support module: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport/UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll
Register platform support module: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport/UnityEditor.WebGL.Extensions.dll
Registered in 0.005863 seconds.
Registering platform support modules:
Registered platform support modules in: 0.2405032s.
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for WebGL target not found
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.59 ms, found 3 plugins.
Preloading 1 native plugins for Editor in 3.16 ms.
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in  3.308 seconds
Registering precompiled user dll's ...
Registered in 0.082678 seconds.
Platform modules already initialized, skipping
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
```

my new C# code is pretty much the same but here it is anyway:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;
public class MyScript {

    public static void MyMethod () {
        var path = "Assets/test.txt";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        writer.WriteLine("Hi there!");
        writer.Close();
        Debug.Log ("Here you put your code");
    }
}
```

SO after I run the command the test.txt file still isn't created.

2nd Edit: I just saw the new answer that logfile indeed needs to be a file name, and after doing so the logfile was created! And this is what it says:

```
LICENSE SYSTEM [2019219 0:45:54] Next license update check is after 2018-08-28T23:32:35


LICENSE SYSTEM [2019219 0:45:54] 00342-20100-00000-AAOEM != 00342-20108-34498-AAOEM

    Built from '2019.1/staging' branch; Version is '2019.1.0b1 (83b3ba1f99df) revision 8631226'; Using compiler version '191627012'
    OS: 'Windows 10  (10.0.0) 64bit' Language: 'en' Physical Memory: 11743 MB
    BatchMode: 1, IsHumanControllingUs: 0, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 0, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 0
    [Package Manager] Server::Start -- Port 51774 was selected



        COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS:
        C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Unity
        -batchmode
        -quit
        -projectPath
        C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty
        -executeMethod
        MyScript.MyMethod
        -logfile
        C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\wow.txt
        Successfully changed project path to: C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty
        C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/totally empty
        Using Asset Import Pipeline V1.
        DisplayProgressbar: Unity Package Manager
        Loading GUID <-> Path mappings...0.000149 seconds
        Loading Asset Database...0.018028 seconds
        AssetDatabase consistency checks...0.041902 seconds
```

so it seems to be opening the project, but the test.txt file is still not created so it seems the function MyScript.MyMethod isn't being called still

Comment: check the return value: `echo %errorlevel%`

Comment: @shingo Hi thanks but I'm not so good with CMD and batch commands, where do I put that? I tried just adding it to the end of the command like this (I changed the project path from before but same idea): "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0b1\Editor\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode  -projectPath "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\totally empty" -execudeMethod Command.Start -logFile C:\Users\eivan\OneDrive\Desktop echo %errorlevel%  but nothing shows in the console after I execute it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the document says, argument for `-logfile` should be a file name, and you seem to use a directory name, this may be the reason.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: Hi thanks! That fixed half of the problem, although do you have any idea why the method isn't executing and creating the test.txt file?

Comment: Actually NVM I just had to wait a few seconds for unity to start up, but it DOES in fact create the text file, thanks!!

Comment: Side question though, do you know how to run a command from an already running unity instance via the command line? I mean how do I access the instance without the -quit argument, after it's started? (If I take out the -quit then try to run the command again, I get an error that a current instance with the project is already running)?

Comment: I think it's hard with command line. But since unity is running you can do something by the C# script. eg create a socket and listen input command.

Comment: hmm interesting idea... My main end-goal is to run the unity editor from my node.js server and run commands from the browser sending to the unity-editor uploaded on the server, so you just gave me the idea to start up a socket (using the Hybrid socket library for example which works well with node.js), and start the socket connection from within the C# command, once it's run from the command line, and then on the node.js side, after "spawning" the unity.exe, wait for the websocket connection and then send commands back and forth like that... So now I have another side question, but related:

Comment: I'm currently attempting to copy my unity editor from Hub/201.0.1b/Editor to my node.js directory in the hopes of using the node.js spawn command to open it up from the command line... but the problem now is that the total size for the unity editor is 3.8GB and I'm wondering if there's a better way / a more compacted version somewhere that can be used well for use on the server, or if you know what folders I can remove to reduce the size (like can I remove Data/PlaybackEngines ?), or am I doing this completely wrong, is there a better way to run Unity from a server?

Comment: What you want to do with the editor? an online version of unity? write a text file is not necessary to open the unity.

Comment: if you must know I'm trying to build asset bundles from the web instead of having to open unity and manually exporting them that way

Comment: I think you have no choice.

Comment: do you by any chance know what folders can be removed, or if there exists a light-weight unity editor somewhere?

Comment: Standard Assets, Documentation, VR (maybe), and unecessary platform in PlaybackEngines

Comment: do I need any playback engines if I won't be building from it?

Comment: No, you can remove them.